# List instance with default url

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, elements-xml

I am currently working with sharepoint hosted apps.

Each app has a List, which i create from visual studio. The client needs some default rows for each list. In some cases a row may have an image. This image is a Url type column with the Format property set to Image

Each default image is contain within 'Images' module for each project. For example:

[image: Structure]

I've tried, with no luck, doing something like the following inside Elements.xml List Instance. However whenever i try to deploy, Visual studio prompts a 'Installation Failed' message with the output: Invalid URL

[image: example]

What could i do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked.

```
<Field Name="Image">~site/Images/Explore.png</Field>
```